# wrap new line variable with <li>

Tags: php, foreach, smarty, whmcs

We are using WHMCS and within the product section I want to wrap the product with `<li></li>` on every new line. So far I have done the following, which gets me all the items but puts them all in one line, but I haven't been able to work out how to assign these stripped values to a new var to be wrapped with the list tag.

```
{foreach from=$product.features key=feature item=value}
        {$value|strip_tags}
      {foreachelse}
        {$product.description|strip_tags}
      {/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
{assign var=lines value="\n"|explode:$product.description|strip_tags}
<ul>
{foreach key=k item=line from=$lines}
<li>{$line}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```