# Laravel 5.8 wrap every new line in an <li></li>

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am currently developing a recipe website with Laravel and I have run into an issue on my recipe show page (show individual recipe). The recipe show page displays the description, ingredients, and step-by-step instructions. 
Both my ingredients and step-by-step instructions are inserted into my DB as one string. The input form requests users to list each ingredient/step on an individual line. I then use the PHP function nl2br() to show the information as a list. However, I would very much like to have control of each new line, preferably be able to wrap an li around each line which I can later style in CSS.

I found this link here on Stackoverflow: [wrap new line variable with <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259445/wrap-new-line-variable-with-li)

I believe this is what I'm looking for, however, I'm not sure how I would adjust this to Laravel. Currently I am using this line of code to retrieve the ingredients and step-by-step:

```
<p>{!! nl2br(e($recipe->directions)) !!}</p>

<p>{!! nl2br(e($recipe->ingredients)) !!}</p>
```

Any help on this would be very much appreciated as it is a little bit outside my current area of expertise! Let me know if I need to clarify this question a little more or provide you guys with some more context! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: what is the output of `$recipe->directions` ?

Comment: `<p>{!! $recipe->directions !!}</p>` did u try this ?

Comment: can you post any demo data which is saved in your db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the input into an array of lines by exploding the string by the new line escape.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $recipe->directions);
```

Output each line with `<li>` elements:

```
<ul>
@foreach ($lines as $line)
<li>{{$line}}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! This was exactly the solution I was looking for! I really appreciate the help :)